# How would I stop a program for taking up all available memory while debugging on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging

Let's say I compile some program with g++ (using the '-g' flag, if that helps). I run it, and my computer simply locks up hence forcing me to restart. The user interface I have simply does not function. Valgrind and gdb do the same.

I could put the output in a file and read it when I start my computer, but this can make debugging an even more time consuming process as I have to restart my computer every time I run the program.

In my case, the program should be taking up a minuscule (at most, 1/400) percentage of memory. A few megabytes in size.

Comment: Ideally how much memory should the program be using? If it were to be running correctly how much memory would it take as a percentage of the total available memory?

Comment: use ulimit to run it in a restricted amount of space and then debug where it runs out.

Comment: To avoid a long reboot, can you run it in a VM?

Comment: A debugger isn't the only remedy, so don't forget the other tools in the toolbox. Maybe it's time to add some instrumentation to record events and measurements?

Comment: Here's a question -- if the machine locks up, how do you know it's a memory contention issue?

Comment: If you are using Linux or another version of Unix, you could limit your applications memory usage with `ulimit -v size` where size is in kilobytes.

Comment: @Iron Savior, Valgrind told me the amount of memory allocated to the program.

Comment: My crystal balls say it's an `if` statement. Soon as this chick gets done polishing them i'll let you know which line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ you can define a global allocator:

```
void *operator new(size_t sz);
void *operator new[](size_t sz);
void operator delete(void *p);
void operator delete[](void *p);
```

and the same for non-throwing versions.

These functions will be called each time you require memory from the heap using `new` for instances or arrays.

What you can do is create a module with these functions implemented that will limit the total amount to say 100Mb and then break with a debugger when this limit is passed to see who is allocating memory.

Note that these user-defined allocation functions will be called only for memory allocated with `new`, and not for memory allocated with `malloc`. Note also that you can use `malloc`/`free` to implement your version (of course you cannot use `new` because it would simply be a recursive call).

One annoying fact is that you must remember the size of the allocated blocks yourself because there's no portable way to ask the size of a `malloc`-ed block.
A simple way to do it is to over-allocate by say 8 bytes and store the block size right before the allocated memory area.

Comment: Agree--Proper instrumentation is a real engineer's tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OS (presumably, Linux-based one) to help you to crash your program once it consumes too much memory. There's an answer on another StackExchange network site about [Limit memory usage for a single Linux process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process). Then you can use debugger to trace point of failure.